# Mysqldump.exe Unknown option --no-beep

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, dump

When I try to run the command :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u root -p******* my_database > backups/my_database_backup_20151221121320.sql
```

it says

```
mysqldump: unknown option '--no-beep'
```

(I'm on windows.)

**What I have tried ?**

- I read and tried many results in google (and here) about moving the "no-beep" away from the `[client]` section in `my.ini` . Did not help. still the same error.
- I tried to check if the `my.ini` file that I change, is the file that actually loaded - and it is, I can change other settings and they are applied.
- I tried running the command without the full path (Only `mysqldump -u..`), still the same error.
- I searched for all the instances of "beep" in the `my.ini` file
- also, when I type `mysql --help` it always shows `no-beep = TRUE` , no matter if I comment or uncomment the "no-beep"

**EDIT :**

using `--no-defaults` I have no problem, but I don't want to change the command.

Some days ago my php script worked fine, I don't know what happened.

Comment: mysqldump.exe seems the culpriti..search the mysqldump.exe in workbench installed directory usually reside parallel in program(x86) folder and try. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all my.ini file
Replace no-beep from everywhere (not only client) 'coz there is no such option.
But to do a temporary fix you can use `no-defaults` as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump.exe" --no-defaults -u root -p******* my_database > backups/my_database_backup_20151221121320.sql
```

Comment: Thank you, of course I tried searching for all instances. And I know that use of "no-defaults" but I am searching for a permament solution.

Comment: The solution here is to find out what / how the no-beep is getting to mysqldump command!  I thought this -> https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68956 bug report has same complain but no solution except it says to remove from my.ini. There is a line in the bug report which says something about mysql workbench...
 Can you also go in the mysqldump.exe file's properties and verify that no-beep is not  coming from there!